# How to make faster reading pdf with camelot-py

Tags: python, pdf, python-camelot

i am using camelot-py to read approximately 15k pdf file but camelot is too slow to read each pdf. For example, if pdf has 5 pages it is acceptable but if pdf has 100 pages it is becoming too slow. How can i solve this problem? I tried some modules for reading pdf files and camelot is best.

I used "stream" method.

Comment: I am one of the maintainers of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/). I doubt very much that camelot has an even faint chance to be faster. What is the camelot time to extract all text from the complete PDF manual (800 pages the new one, 1310 page the old one)? For PyMuPDF it's below 4 seconds for all pages in each case.

Comment: @JorjMcKie i know PyMuPDF is faster. Camelot extracted all text from a pdf that contains 99 pages as pandas dataframe  correctly but it takes minutes (>6-7 minutes). can you check [link](https://www.kap.org.tr/tr/ek-indir/4028328c86845fa80186bc7dc7300c6c). It has only 3 pages. If i use PyMuPDF, it does not return empyt cells. For example, the row that contains "SKTAS" has empty cell between 27/10/21 and 3,680000 cells. Because of that the pandas dataframe becomes unstructured and to be complex to rearrange. I could not find any solution about that.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Indeed, PyMuPDF is a general tool and not specialized on table detection or table content extraction. While it does detect all text details, it always requires app code to find or determine e.g. column borders or table headers.

Comment: Have you tried [pdfplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber)? `tables = [ page.extract_table(dict(vertical_strategy="text", horizontal_strategy="text")) for page in pdfplumber.open("file.pdf") ]` extracts everything on your example pdf.